# Android - Open 3rd Tab from Intent fired from Dialog in Fragment

Tags: java, android, android-fragments

I have ALr.java class and FragHandler. FragHandler has Tablayout and viewpager. ALR and FragHandler code is writtern below. I want to open Settings tab which is third tab in FragHandler from click on ALR i.e. rl.setonclicklisterner by calling activatealert method.

MyFragHandler Class

```
public class FragHandler extends AppCompatActivity 
    TabLayout tabLayout;
    Toolbar customtoolbar;
    SharedPreferences sharedPreferences;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.alstabopener);

        sharedPreferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);



        tabLayout = (TabLayout) findViewById(R.id.tab_layout);
        tabLayout.addTab(tabLayout.newTab().setText("1"));
        tabLayout.addTab(tabLayout.newTab().setText("2"));
        tabLayout.addTab(tabLayout.newTab().setText("Settings"));
        tabLayout.setTabGravity(TabLayout.GRAVITY_FILL);




        final ViewPager viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);
        final AlsViewChanger adapter = new AlsViewChanger(getSupportFragmentManager(), tabLayout.getTabCount());
        viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);

        viewPager.addOnPageChangeListener(new TabLayout.TabLayoutOnPageChangeListener(tabLayout));
        tabLayout.setOnTabSelectedListener(new TabLayout.OnTabSelectedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onTabSelected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {
                viewPager.setCurrentItem(tab.getPosition());
            }

            @Override
            public void onTabUnselected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onTabReselected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {

            }
        });


    }





}
```

and my ALR.java from where I m trying to open tab 3.

```
public class ALR extends Fragment  {


    TextView rl, 




    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) throws NullPointerException {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.ar, container, false);



        rl = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.reto);


               rl.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {


                    activatealert();

                });    
    public void activatealert() {
        MaterialDialog activateald = new MaterialDialog.Builder(getActivity())
                .content("In order to use these services, please click settings and set appropriate options to activate Where R U feature.")
                .title("Activate Where R U")
                .positiveColor(Color.BLUE)
                .negativeColor(Color.RED)
                .positiveText("Settings")
                .negativeText("Cancel")
                .onPositive(new MaterialDialog.SingleButtonCallback() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(@NonNull MaterialDialog dialog, @NonNull DialogAction which) {
                        Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(),FragHandler.class);
                        intent.putExtra("Settings",2);
                        startActivity(intent);

                    }
                })
                .show();
    }
}
```

it opens tabbed activitiy but First Tab not third as required. Pls guide.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Edit Based on your code:

remove the `OnTabSelectedListener`, you don't need it.

just add

```
tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(viewPager);
```

Here's the full code:

```
public class FragHandler extends AppCompatActivity 
    TabLayout tabLayout;
    Toolbar customtoolbar;
    SharedPreferences sharedPreferences;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.alstabopener);

        sharedPreferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);

        tabLayout = (TabLayout) findViewById(R.id.tab_layout);
        tabLayout.addTab(tabLayout.newTab().setText("1"));
        tabLayout.addTab(tabLayout.newTab().setText("2"));
        tabLayout.addTab(tabLayout.newTab().setText("Settings"));
        tabLayout.setTabGravity(TabLayout.GRAVITY_FILL);

        final ViewPager viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);
        final AlsViewChanger adapter = new AlsViewChanger(getSupportFragmentManager(), tabLayout.getTabCount());
        viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);

        tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(viewPager);
        int tabToSelect = getIntent().getIntExtra("Settings”, 0);
        viewPager.setCurrentItem(tabToSelect);
    }

}
```

Please check the

```
int tabToSelect = getIntent().getIntExtra("Settings”, 0);
```

I just assumed if you wanted to do so. Change it according if you don't need it.

It's hard to answer without much details, but here are my few suggestion based on assumptions:

1) You want to start an activity `FragHandler` which has multiple tabs. TabLayout is associated with `ViewPager`. so in that case, after you set adapter to `ViewPager`, call `viewPager.setCurrentItem(2)`. If you have only tabs, then you can try `tabLayout.getTabAt(2).select()`. This should trigger your `OnTabSelectedListener` where you might already have code for replacing fragment.

2) The fragment which is having dialog is inside the same `TabLayout` where 3rd tab you are asking for is. In this case put the following code in onClick of settings button:

```
// If ViewPager, then make it public in YourActivity
((YourActivity)getActivity()).viewPager.setCurrentItem(2);

// If TabLayout without ViewPager, then also make it public
((YourActivity)getActivity()).tabLayout.getTabAt(2).select();
```

And post as much details as possible so that you can get correct answer

Comment: I updated body with more information. pls read and guide. as neither 1 or 2 case can help because I do not have tablayout and viewpager in ALR.java class from where I m calling tab 3.

Comment: @Panache if I understood correct, case 1 is what you need. You are starting FragHandler Activity from ALR.java with passing "Settings" flag. now in onCreate of FragHandler you might be initializing your ViewPager & TabLayout. Just below that code, try & check by adding a line like 
viewPager.setCurrentItem(2); this will programmatically make your 3rd Tab Selected.

Comment: I have added both class and better info, pls look

Comment: // If TabLayout without ViewPager, then also make it public
((YourActivity)getActivity()).tabLayout.getTabAt(2).select(); worked.Thanks